# DatePicker doesn't work when stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus option is true

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In [this example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/OqccEMROZgjz0uV4Khch?preview) clicking on a date it is possible to edit it, but if you use the option "stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus", the date picker doesn't work anymore. Is it possible to fix this?

```
<AgGridReact
   stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus // without this line works fine
   columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
   components={this.state.components}
   onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
   rowData={this.state.rowData}
 />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having "stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus" set to true, when you click on a date, the input tag is gone, so the reference for your datepicker gets lost.

I had the same issue and I solved it doing this:

- Change your custom component settings to work in a popup:

  ```
  Datepicker.prototype.isPopup = function() {
      return true;
  };
  ```
- Then, call to stopEditing() method on select event in your datepicker:

  ```
  $(this.eInput).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          params.stopEditing();
      }
  });
  ```

I have created a new working fork from your example [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/eKqEzVOFHoVSrWEF)

Comment: Man THANK YOU :D

Comment: When we change month or click on any other disabled part. It fails again.

Answer (score -2):

stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus = true